# Cake php clear fields when edit

Tags: php, cakephp

I want if someone click on edit button , all fields can show but the 1 specific fields details should be hidden how can i adjust in this command line , cake php 2

```
echo $this->Form->input('contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions

1st    put an empty value to this form on view side.

```
> echo $this->Form->input('contact' array('value' => '');
```

2nd Solution is from model controlers unset the default value which is auto filling the forms

```
unset($this->request->data['Company']['contact']);
```